# javascript code to create html select menu not populating in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, select, internet-explorer-8

This code works in IE10+ and Chrome, but I need it to work for IE8.

I think it works up until the point I marked with the comment, because a drop down menu will be generated and scaled to the correct size, but it won't be filled with any options to select. Furthermore, the IE8 debugger doesn't give any errors, it just doesn't execute correctly.

```
create_menu("letter", "letters_select_menu", ["a","b","c"]);

function create_menu(div_id, sel_id, menu_options) {

    var myDiv = document.getElementById(div_id);

    // create select menu and size
    var selectList = document.createElement("select");
    selectList.setAttribute("id", sel_id);
    selectList.setAttribute("size", menu_options.length);
    myDiv.appendChild(selectList);

    // i think it works up until this point

    // populate the menu with the options from the array
    for (var i = 0; i < menu_options.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.setAttribute("value", menu_options[i]);
        option.text = menu_options[i];
        selectList.appendChild(option);
    }
};
```

On IE10 I see this:

[image]

On IE8 I see this:

[image]

Can you see anything in the second block of code that might be incompatible with IE8 and causing the problem? I've been commenting stuff out with no results because they're all the same commands as used in the first block.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. `option.text` doesn't work in IE8 or IE9, so I changed it to `option.innerHTML` and now it works.

For the final result:

```
function create_menu(div_id, sel_id, menu_options) {

    var myDiv = document.getElementById(div_id);

    // create select menu and size
    var selectList = document.createElement("select");
    selectList.setAttribute("id", sel_id);
    selectList.setAttribute("size", menu_options.length);
    myDiv.appendChild(selectList);

    // populate the menu with the options from the array
    for (var i = 0; i < menu_options.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.setAttribute("value", menu_options[i]);
        option.innerHTML = menu_options[i];
        selectList.appendChild(option);
    }
};
```

Comment: innerHTML may be unsecure (xss).

Comment: True. It should be okay for this purpose, but do you recommend an alternative?

Comment: Use jQuery: $(option).text(menu_options[i]);

Answer (score 0):

Use the select's "add" function.

```
var sel = document.createElement('select');

var option = documeng.createElement('option');
option.value = '1';
option.text = 'Option 1';

sel.add(option, null);
```